# Google Drive API Get files of the last week/last Day

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm looking for property in google drive API to get google spreadsheet file that's I upload them last week

this URL  gives all the files that I have on my google drive. I want to filter this URL more with TIME Per week

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'&access_token=",$access_token$
```

any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: For this question, can I propose a workaround using ``q``? If you had solved your issue and you don't need my workaround, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike it will be  a pleasure if you give me workaround using q to extract just the last files per day or week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that @DaImTo's answer is correct. So how about this workaround? When the files are uploaded to Google Drive, the created time and modified time become the same to the uploaded time. In this workaround, this is used.

From your question, it seems that you use Drive API v3. So you can use the following query. As a sample, it assumes that the last week is `2018-04-01T00:00:00`.

```
mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00' and createdTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00'
```

#### Note :

- Please modify the date to your environment.
- If you want to retrieve files using the range of date, please modify as follows.

  - `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00' and modifiedTime < '2018-04-02T00:00:00' and createdTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00' and createdTime < '2018-04-02T00:00:00'`
  - This means that files uploaded from `2018-04-01T00:00:00` to `2018-04-02T00:00:00` are retrieved.
- In the case of this workaround, it cannot be known whether those are the files that had been uploaded. If you manually created files for 1 week, this query also retrieves such files.

  - If you want to retrieve only the uploaded files, how about using the unique filename? For example, it's `upload-###`. By this, you can use the following query.

    - `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00' and createdTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00' and name contains 'upload-'`

#### Reference :

- [Search for Files for Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

I'm not sure whether this is useful for your environment. So if this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: so this query it will give me the last file from last week automatically? means no need to enter the date again for the next week _

Comment: @MokiNex In this workaround, the date is required to be updated when the script is run. I think that this can be achieved in the script. But if this workaround is not what you want, I'm sorry. Should I delete my answer? If you want, please tell me.

Comment: i like your workaround but it will be perfect if I find a solution how to automatically give me the file of the last week no need to put manually the date. otherwise, if you have an idea to extract the date of this  weeks everytime let me know please

Comment: @MokiNex  Unfortunately, there is not the query for directly using last week. And the date for modifiedTime and createdTime is required to be RFC3339 format like ``2018-04-01T00:00:00``. So when you want to use the query with last week, it is required to make the script for retrieving the date using the language you want to use. If you can give me the information about the language, I might be able to propose a sample.

Comment: I'm trying now to use your query manually but its don't display for me the files `ERROR GET Request          2:157      Execute failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query"`

Comment: `join("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00' and createdTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00'&access_token=",$access_token$)`

Comment: @MokiNex I'm sorry for the inconvenienve. The query parameters are often required to be encoded. Can you try again by doing url encode? When ``q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00' and createdTime > '2018-04-01T00:00:00'`` is encoded, it becomes ``q=mimeType%3d%27application%2fvnd%2egoogle%2dapps%2espreadsheet%27%20and%20modifiedTime%20%3e%20%272018%2d04%2d01T00%3a00%3a00%27%20and%20createdTime%20%3e%20%272018%2d04%2d01T00%3a00%3a00%27``

Comment: it works now for the date I find how to get to extract the date of my machine and add it to a variable. so now my only problem how can I add this variable to the query

Comment: @MokiNex You can use the same date to ``modifiedTime`` and ``createdTime`` as a string value. At that time, please do URL encode for the string value of date. If in order to implement it, you have more question on the specific language, you can post it as new question. By this, many users including me can think of it.

Answer (score 2):

The [q parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) is used for searching in Google drive.   It does not have an option to search by uploaded date.

I suggest that you running the request you have an sort and filter the results locally.

Comment: Do you have an approach how to deal that locally Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Only way to find newly uploaded is to maintain a local list of fileIDs from an initial crawl of the drive folder. Then when you download the list again you check to see if each fileID exists in the local list. If not, it's a newly uploaded file. Depending on the density of the folder you're searching and power of your client device, this may incur too much overhead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).